# Contour Integration of Line Segments

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to use contour integration to find the integral of:

$$ \int_\gamma ydz $$

where we have the union of line segments from $0$ to $i$ and then to $i+2$.

I simply do not understand how to do this. I missed the lecture on the introduction to this due to being sick.

I attempted to do:

$$ \int_0^i ydz + \int_i^{i+2} ydz $$ but did not get the right answer, which is $2+\frac{i}{2}$.I believe we are supposed to use Parameterization but I don't understand how to Parameterize a curve.

Comment: what about $z=it,0\le t\le 1$ for first path and $z=t+i,0\le t\le 2$ for the segond path?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma_1$ be the line segment from $0$ to $i$, and let $\gamma_2$ be the line segment from $i$ to $i+2$. Then $\gamma = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2$, and so $$\int_\gamma y\, dz = \int_{\gamma_1} y\, dz + \int_{\gamma_2} y\, dz.$$ Parametrize $\gamma_1$ by setting $z = it$, $0 \le t \le 1$. Then $$\int_{\gamma_1} y\, dz = \int_0^1 t (i\, dt) = i \int_0^1 t\, dt = \frac{i}{2}.$$ Parametrize $\gamma_2$ by setting $z = t + i$, $0 \le t \le 2$. Then

$$\int_{\gamma_2} y\, dz = \int_0^2 1\, dt = 2.$$

Thus

$$\int_{\gamma} y\, dz = 2 + \frac{i}{2}.$$

Comment: Could you explain how you did the parametrization? I am very confused on that part.

Comment: @Frumpy in case of $\gamma_1$, every point on it is of the form $it$, $0 \le t \le 1$. So a natural parametrization is $z = it$, $0 \le t \le 1$. In case of $\gamma_2$, every point on it is of the form $i + t$, where $0 \le t \le 2$. So a natural parametrization for that is $z = i + t$, $0 \le t \le 2$. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "form" $it$, and why is $t$ between 0 and 1? I just don't understand the concept of parameterization.

Comment: I mean $\gamma_1 = \{it : 0 \le t \le 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let, $z=x+iy$. Then , $dz=dx+idy$.

> Remember that any complex number of the form $x+iy$ represents the order pair $(x,y)$.

So, $0$ to $i$ means from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(0,1)$. That means when $x=0$ then take limit of $y$ as $0$ to $1$. Now, $x=0\implies dx=0.$

Similarly, $i$ to $i+2$ means from the point $(0,1)$ to the point $(2,1)$. That means when $y=1$ then take the limit of $x$ as $0$ to $2$. Now, $y=1\implies dy=0$.

See the following figure for the line integral.
[image]

Then, $$\int_{\gamma}ydz=\int_{y=0}^{1}y(idy)+\int_{x=0}^{2}1.dx=\frac{i}{2}+2$$

Comment: Is there any way you can explain the parameterization again? I am very confused.

Comment: I can't understand your question. In my answer anywhere I did not apply any parameter.

Comment: See i understand the line integral and why those are our bounds for the two integrals, but I do not understand why we got $y$ for the first integral and $1$ for the second integral.

Comment: Just find the equation of the lines $OA$ & $AB$. I think it helps you

Comment: I see now, can you by any chance explain why cand got $y=t$ and $y=1$?

Comment: $z=it\implies x+iy=0+it$. Comparing real & imaginary parts we get $x=0$ & $y=t$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21156/discussion-between-frumpy-and-panja-s).

Comment: So if we had $\int_\gamma xdz$ would we have $x=0$ for the first integral and then $x=t$ for the second integral?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_\gamma ydz=\int_{\gamma_1}ydz+\int_{\gamma_2}ydz$$
then
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma_1}ydz\\
z&=it,0\le t\le 1\\
dz&=idt\\
y&=t\\
\int_{\gamma_1}ydz&=\int_0^1(t)(idt)\\
&=i\int_0^1tdt\\
&=i\left.\frac{t^2}{2}\right|_0^1\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma_2}ydz\\
z&=t+i,0\le t\le 2\\
dz&=dt\\
y&=1\\
\int_{\gamma_2}ydz&=\int_0^2(1)(dt)\\
&=\int_0^2dt\\
&=2\end{align}$$
wich gives
$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma ydz&=\int_{\gamma_1}ydz+\int_{\gamma_2}ydz\\
&=2+\frac{i}{2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I understand why you got the parameterization but I do not understand why for the first one you got $y=t$ and on the second one why you got $y=1$?

Comment: $z=x+yi$, in first $z=x+iy=it$ and in the segond $z=x+iy=t+i$